# JQuery, cannot assign data attribute after creation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add some data attributes to a list element after creation.

```
  var el = document.createElement('li');
  el.className = "list-group-item";
  el.attr({"data-content": contentForm, "data-type": contentType, "data-number": value});
```

The error is 'Uncaught TypeError: el.attr is not a function'

I follow another discussion here, and I cannot find the issue...

Comment: There is no DOM node method `attr()` BUT  `setAttribute()`

Comment: You Cannot use `el` jQuery methods on JS DOMElement. Use `$(el).attr({...`

Comment: You do not use attr to set data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`attr()` is a jquery function you can't call it on DOM element, try to use **[setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)** or make your `el` a jquery element before calling **[attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** :

```
el.setAttribute();
//OR
$(el).attr();
```

If you want ro add `data` attributes you should use **[data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** e.g :

```
$(el).data({content: contentForm, type: contentType, number: value});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use jQuery, do the whole thing in jQuery.

```
var el = $('<li/>').addClass('list-group-item').attr({"data-content": contentForm, "data-type": contentType, "data-number": value});
```

Comment: You do not set data using attr!

Comment: You think? It changes the HTML, it doesn't update the global variable that jQuery creates on page load.

Comment: What global variable?

Comment: Internally, jQuery creates an empty object called $.cache, which is used to store the values you set via the data method. Each DOM element you add data to, is assigned a unique ID which is used as a key in the $.cache object.